# android compose TextField how to set like css word-break: break-all;?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want break all word just like css word-break: break-all; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

how to set it ?

```
var source by remember {
  mutableStateOf("""{"name":"开屏看你好丫丫告","desc":"我是描述","key":0,"activityIds":["com.alibaba.wireless.launch.home.V5HomeActivity"],"rules":[{"matches":["[id=`com.alibaba.wireless:id/v5_splash_over`]"]}]}""")
}

OutlinedTextField(
  value = source,
  onValueChange = { source = it },
  maxLines = 8,
  modifier = Modifier
    .padding(10.dp)
    .fillMaxWidth(),
)
```

This picture is the behavior of the above code, but it is not the effect I want

[image]